# convert ical to table and include recurring events

Tags: bash, shell, awk

In a bash script this command is used to convert an ics calendar file into a table

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}/^DTSTART/{dtstart=$2}/^SUMMARY/{summary=$2}/^END:VEVENT/{print substr(dtstart,7,2)"/"substr(dtstart,5,2)"/"substr(dtstart,1,4),sprintf("%02d",substr(dtstart,10,2)+3)":"substr(dtstart,12,2),summary}' iCal.ics
```

It converts this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:emailaddress@gmail.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Asia/Nicosia
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T050000Z
DTEND:20221016T053000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:494jpt5pm5lhfn47mv1eppp0hm@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143242Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143242Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 8am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T040000Z
DTEND:20221016T043000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:55j049svjglavmlqu8evdfbe8n@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143233Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143233Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 7am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20221016T030000Z
DTEND:20221016T033000Z
DTSTAMP:20221016T144146Z
UID:054od4tq8eisl2s6eoa33rsdbc@google.com
CREATED:20221016T143220Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20221016T143220Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:test event 6am
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

To this:

```
16/10/2022 08:00 test event 8am
16/10/2022 07:00 test event 7am
16/10/2022 06:00 test event 6am
```

The problem appears when an event is marked as recurring. In that case the event is ignored. This is an example of 2 events marked as recurring.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20220930T100000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20220930T104500
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=FR
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221230T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221216T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221223T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221118T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221111T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221104T100000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221028T100000
DTSTAMP:20221101T182355Z
UID:uidhere@google.com
CREATED:20220923T075114Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20220923T075148Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:reccuring test1 99435181
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT

BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221012T110000
DTEND;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221012T114500
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=WE
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221228T110000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221221T110000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20230104T110000
EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Nicosia:20221109T110000
DTSTAMP:20221101T182355Z
UID:uidhere@google.com
CREATED:20221006T134902Z
DESCRIPTION:test description
LAST-MODIFIED:20221006T134922Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:reccuring test2 99435181
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
```

How can the command be modified to include recurring events in the mentioned output?

Comment: fiw, cutting-n-pasting your sample data into my env and then running your `awk` script *does* generate output for the 2x 'recurring' entries; namely: `30/09/2022 13:00 reccuring test1 99435181` and `12/10/2022 14:00 reccuring test2 99435181`

Comment: I'll test it again

Comment: the `awk` script is pretty basic so I'm guessing there may be an issue with your actual data file (that doesn't show up when you cut-n-pasted into this question); wondering if there may be some odd characters in your file ... using a `iCal.ics` file with *just* the 2 'recurring' entries, what does the following generate: `grep -E 'DSTART|SUMMARY|END:VEVENT' iCal.ics | od -c` (if you're unsure then update the question with this `od -c` output)

Comment: this is the output https://pastecode.io/s/t30shjzr

Comment: the `od -c` output should be cut-n-pasted into the question; providing links to offsite images is typically frowned upon for a couple reasons ... no guarantee that link will be active in the future should someone come across this question ... placing the output in the question, as text, allows us to cut-n-paste into our own environment (not an issue in this case but on occasion users post their inputs as images)

Comment: having said that ... the image shows your data file contains windows/dos line endings (`\r\n`), and while your code still works if I convert my file to use windows/dos line endings, I would want to rule this out as an issue; one idea for removing `\r` characters with the `awk/gsub()` function ... `awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {gsub(/\r/,"")} /^DSTART/ .... rest of script remains the same ...}' iCal.ics`)

Comment: Is it really acceptable to handle time zones by adding + 3 to the hour? (And without even checking whether that goes over 23?)